# .NET Framework 3.5, Assembly Binding Logging

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-6

I am getting the following error:

**Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.DynamicData, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

I've researched the problem and some of the solutions are pointing to Turning on Assembly Binding Logging.

I'm confused as to what this error is.  So my question:

***What does this error mean and how do I resolve it?  I am not hosting the site in a shared hosting scenario, it is on a single server running .NET Framework 3.5.0 using IIS 6.0**

**Edit  .Net Framework 3.5 SP 1 isn't installed on the server.  The missing assemblies are apart of that Service Pack.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that the SP1 is installed for .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Visual Studio; remove the reference to the assembly, and then re-add it by hunting it down on the file system, or if it's in the GAC (c:\windows\assembly)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.  It appears that on our dev machines we are running Framework 3.5.1 but running 3.5.0 on the server.